# How can I access my private variables across different classes?

Tags: java, global-variables

I am working on creating a hangman-like game. It reads from a `.txt` file of four letter words and randomly selects one of the words and the player will then have 7 tries to guess the word...I have not completed that all yet, I am having trouble accessing my variables from one class to the other. Here is my code:

```
package wordguessinggame2;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class WordGuessingGame2 {

    static class RandomWordProvider {

        public final List<String> words;

        public RandomWordProvider() {
        words = readFile();
    }

    public int randomInteger() {
        int randomInt = (int) (Math.random() * words.size());
        return randomInt;
    }

    private String getWord() {
        int randomPosition = randomInteger();
        String randomWord = words.get(randomPosition);
        return randomWord;
    }

    private List<String> readFile() {

        List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            File fourLetterWords = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"),"Documents/FourLetterWords.txt");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(fourLetterWords);

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            if (line!=null && !line.isEmpty()) {
                wordsList.add(line);
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
    return wordsList ;
    }
}
    public static class PlayerCharacterEntry {

        private String playerEntry() {
            Scanner characterEntry = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
            String playerInput = characterEntry.next();
            playerInput = playerInput.toUpperCase();
            return playerInput;
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner wantToPlay = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Welcome to the word guessing game! Would you like to play? ");
        String playerAnswer = wantToPlay.next();

        if (playerAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            System.out.print("\nYour objective is to guess a four letter word by entering"
            + "\nletters on your keyboard. If you can not guess the word in seven attempts,"
            + "\nyou lose! You will be told if the letter you entered is in the word, and"
            + "\nyou will be told if the letter you entered is not in the word. You will be"
            + "\nallowed to guess the word any time during your seven attempts. If at anytime"
            + "\nyou would like to terminate the game, enter the word 'terminate'. Good Luck!"
            + "\n \n");
    }
        if (playerAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
            System.out.print("Maybe another time!");
            System.exit(0);
    }

RandomWordProvider randomWordProvider = new RandomWordProvider();
PlayerCharacterEntry playerCharacterEntry = new PlayerCharacterEntry();

randomWordProvider.getWord();
playerCharacterEntry.playerEntry();

if (randomWord.containsIgnoreCase(playerInput)){

    }

}
}
```

Here at the bottom I am trying to access randomWord and playerInput from my other classes but I don't know how to do that. I am still fairly new to programming so I don't know how to do everything yet. Would I do a get and set method for each variable? I have tried doing that and I'm having a lot of trouble with that. If someone could show me how to access variables across classes it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what´s the problem with the creation of accessors?

Comment: @rafalopez79 well when I create private String playerInput; and then get and set methods. then my instance stops working in my main method.

Comment: A private member is by definition only accessible within the class itself. I you want to access it by another class use get/set like rafalopez79 said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly simplified example where the `RandomWordProvider` and `PlayerCharacterEntry` classes are NOT nested inside `WordGuessingGame2`.
I show only the methods I needed to modify:

```
class RandomWordProvider {   
    String getWord() {
        int randomPosition = randomInteger();
        String randomWord = words.get(randomPosition);
        return randomWord;
    }

    // ...
}

class PlayerCharacterEntry {
    String playerEntry() {
        Scanner characterEntry = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
        String playerInput = characterEntry.next();
        playerInput = playerInput.toUpperCase();
        return playerInput;
    }
}

class WordGuessingGame2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // ...

        RandomWordProvider randomWordProvider = new RandomWordProvider();
        PlayerCharacterEntry playerCharacterEntry = new PlayerCharacterEntry();

        randomWordProvider.getWord();
        playerCharacterEntry.playerEntry();
    }
}
```

Notice that I dropped the `private` modifier from the `getWord` and `playerEntry` methods,
otherwise they are not accessible from `WordGuessingGame2`.

It's good to start with the strictest possible modifiers, 
and then reduce the restrictions as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**No, private variables are only accessable from within the class it self.**  It's highly recommended that you create public getters and setters to maintain the OO principle of encapsulation.